# Business Objects/Custom Classes DAL Design

Tags: asp.net, data-access-layer, business-objects

I need some advice on how to handle this scenario.  My application has many tables and custom classes mapped to those tables.  Let's use the following as an example (pseudo-code):

```
Public Class Country
Name As String
Language As String
Capital As String
President As String

Public Class State
Name As String
Capital As String
Country As String

Public Class City
Name As String
State As String
Country As String
```

Retrieving an individual object of any of these classes is straight forward.  Retrieving lists of any of these objects is straight forward as well.

Where I need guidance is how to retrieve a combination of these objects.  For example we may need to display a list of City Names and Country Presidents (excludes the State Class).  What object should I use to hold that data?  I want to avoid retrieving the State data because trips to the database are expensive. I typically present the information using repeaters so I also need an object that is easily bindable to a repeater.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of .NET? SOunds like an onld one now knowing anonymous types for projections.

Comment: 3.5.  I'm researching anonymous types as we speak.  thanks for the lead.

Comment: I would suggest breaking away from these classes and using specific classes for the lists that you want to retrieve. For example, `CityListItem`, `CountryPresidentListItem`, and so on. In any case, if you stick to the classes that you have at the moment, you will eventually reach a point where they will not be fit for your use-cases -- that is, you can shape them only to such an extent.